# Elementary OS, 18.04 - Nvidia driver is not working. Nouveau turned off, X server empty

Tags: drivers, xorg, nvidia, resolution, nouveau

I am struggling to install a Nvidia driver for almost two weeks and slowly giving up. I reinstalled the newly Elementary OS probably 5 times already and still cannot find a way how to install the driver.

I went through many guides on the forum and internet but none of them worked. Now I stuck on the low resolution 640x480 and any driver I installed not working. I have Nvidia GTX 980 graphic card, and last few days tried to install driver 465, 460, 450, 390. Result was: even the "nvidia-smi" showing that driver is installed, the X server is empty and low resolution is still cutting my eyes.

The secure boot in IOS is turned off, nouveau workaround applied in the config file.

These are added in: /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf (according: https://newbedev.com/how-to-disable-nouveau-kernel-driver)

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

I tried also these links: none of them worked though :(. Nvidia drivers reset after update and now monitor is "unknown" and stuck in 640x480 Nvidia driver problems on 18.04

https://github.com/lutris/docs/blob/master/InstallingDrivers.md Completely removing old Nvidia drivers https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=339381&sid=47bef6e9d81174f29e405858bcc98d28&start=20 https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1895521#p1895521 Unable to get nvidia running on ubuntu 18.04.2 https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Is there normal way to install a current nvidia driver ? or am I forced to use a nouveau or old 390 version ? (I had old one running when I installed it manually few days ago, but I realized when kernel update will come I had to re-intall it again, so tried to work again on auto updating driver, via additional driver center).

I will be really grateful if anyone can shade a light and help me. The OS reinstall is not a problem at this time, so I am willing to try any guide, just to have a latest driver working, even after reboot. With proper resolution of course.

Many thanks.

(if any output needed please tell me, I will provide it)

output from nvidia-smi:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat May 15 10:04:13 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 980     Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   34C    P0    49W / 300W |      0MiB /  4040MiB |      2%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

EDIT/UPDATE:

Sorry for the comments, and yes I run the `update-initramfs -u` command.
here are outputs:

```
$ lsmod | grep -iE 'nouv|nv'
nvidia_uvm            991232  0
nvidia_drm             53248  1
nvidia_modeset       1228800  1 nvidia_drm
nvidia              34123776  2 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        188416  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   491520  4 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm
nvme                   49152  1
nvme_core             106496  3 nvme
doozie@doozie:/etc/X11$ 
doozie@doozie:/etc/X11$ 
doozie@doozie:/etc/X11$

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*
```

Comment: The nvidia driver is being loaded (otherwise nvidia-smi wouldn't show the driver version number).  the problem is almost certainly in your xorg.conf - maybe you need `Option "UseEDID" "True"` in your Monitor section and/or `Option "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +0+0"` in your Screen section.    If your monitor is really ancient or unusual, you may need to manually define the modelines.   What does `xrandr` say?

Comment: I have two monitors: one is: 24" LG and second one is 20" LG.
output: 
$xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*

Comment: I am bit skeptical about this note in nvidia-smi, 
"No running processes found"

Comment: Did you run `update-initramfs -u` after blacklisting nouveau?   what does `lsmod | grep -iE 'nouv|nvidia'` display?   and `dmesg | grep -iE 'nouv|nvid'`.   BTW, edit your question and add the output of `xrandr` and `lsmod ...` and `dmesg ...` **to your question**., not in a comment.

Comment: OK, that's definitely using the proprietary nvidia driver.   `xrandr` says your monitor is 1024x768, which doesn't seem right for either a 24" or 20" LCD monitor.    Try viewing in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` with `less`, see if/where it mentions EDID or LG or 1024x768,  or if there were any error messages (e.g. `grep '\(EE\)' /var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: It might be the LG brand.  I've got an LG 42LD560 LCD TV connected to my mythtv box, and the EDID data it returns when X queries it is garbage.  I had to get a working EDID file for it from somewhere and tell X to use that instead of querying the monitor.   Of course, this LCD TV is approx 10 years old, so LG might have improved since then (possibly not, they seem more interested in SpywareTVs than anything else these days).   IIRC, I might have used `read-edid` from the console, without X running....but it was a long time ago.